# UILabel not showing Text String that shows in Console

Tags: ios, objective-c, xml, uitableview, uilabel

**I have a UILabel that won't show up.**

If I use `api2Cell.labelDescription.text = @"Hello";` then the text shows up, but when I try to get the text from XML (which shows up in the console) it won't show up in the label.

```
FeedRSS *feedDan = (FeedRSS *)model;
MRWebListTableViewCellTwo  *api2Cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"YourAPI2Cell"];
NSString *description = [self removeHTMLTags:feedDan.description];
api2Cell.labelDescription.text = description;
NSLog(@"DescriptionString RSS: %@", description);
```

Console shows:

```
DescriptionString RSS: 
BOSTON -- Jared Sullinger will always wonder what might have been if Evan Turner had returned for his senior season at Ohio State. evanalmighty12 on...
```

But label is blank.  Doesn't show `null`, just stays blank.  Sometimes when I tap and hold the cell, the text will show up for a moment.  So I just don't get it.  I've set breakpoints, etc.

Can anyone help?  Thanks!

Here is the method `removeHTMLTags`:

```
- (NSString *)removeHTMLTags:(NSString *)str {
    NSMutableString *temp_str = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:str];
    NSRange openTag = [temp_str rangeOfString:@"<"];
    NSRange closeTag = [temp_str rangeOfString:@">"];

    while (openTag.length > 0) {
        NSRange range;
        range.location = openTag.location;
        range.length = (closeTag.location - openTag.location) + 1;
        [temp_str setString:[temp_str stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:@""]];

        openTag = [temp_str rangeOfString:@"<"];
        closeTag = [temp_str rangeOfString:@">"];
    }

    [temp_str replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"&Auml;" withString:@"Ä" options:NSLiteralSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [temp_str length])];
    [temp_str replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"&Aring;" withString:@"Å" options:NSLiteralSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [temp_str length])];
    [temp_str replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"&AElig;" withString:@"Æ" options:NSLiteralSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [temp_str length])];


    while ([temp_str rangeOfString:@"  "].location != NSNotFound) {
        [temp_str replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"  " withString:@" " options:NSLiteralSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [temp_str length])];
    }

    while ([temp_str rangeOfString:@" ."].location != NSNotFound) {
        [temp_str replaceOccurrencesOfString:@" ." withString:@"." options:NSLiteralSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [temp_str length])];
    }

    while ([temp_str rangeOfString:@" ,"].location != NSNotFound) {
        [temp_str replaceOccurrencesOfString:@" ," withString:@"," options:NSLiteralSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [temp_str length])];
    }

    while ([temp_str rangeOfString:@" ;"].location != NSNotFound) {
        [temp_str replaceOccurrencesOfString:@" ;" withString:@";" options:NSLiteralSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [temp_str length])];
    }

    return temp_str;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be that's because there's a new line in the start of `description`.

Try using:

```
api2Cell.labelDescription.text = [description stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
```

Comment: This is awesome thank you so much it worked!!!  But quick question because I'm still not totally seeing the "new line in the start of description".  Where do you see that?  I know I'm missing it, and want to make sure I fully understand you're solution, even though I know it is right and works.  Thanks!

Comment: normally with the web content it's not visible. But in your log, line, "BOSTON -- Jared Sullinger..." starts from new line. That made me think so.